# Order Scala methods alphabetically (by name) using Intellij IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I wanted to order Scala functions alphabetically, I'm using Intellij IDEA is there is a way to do that ?

Comment: the functions are ordered alphebatically if i am not wrong. It shows `consutuctor -> functions -> variables` in this order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *Settings > Editor > Code Style > Scala > Arrangement*
2. In *Matching Rules* click **+** to add a new rule
3. If you want to order `def` without modifiers (which is public by default) in *Type* click **function** and in *Modifier* click **public**, in **Order** choose **order by name**. Then click **OK**.
   [image]
4. After that you can open your file with unordered methods, click *Code* > *Rearrange Code* and they will be ordered by name.

**PS** I used *IDEA Community Edition 2019.3*